# как передавать хуки из одного файла в другой React.js

Tags: reactjs

У меня есть два файла где в одном лежат хуки в другой компонент. И как мне в компонент передать эти хуки ?

Comment: Импортировать нужные хуки в компонент...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй вот так:

В файле с хуком -

```
export default function Hoocks() {
const [hoock, setHoock] = useState();
    return {
    setHoock, hoock
    }
}
```

Это в компоненте -

```
import Hoock from "./Hoock"

 const {
    setHoock, hoock
 }  = Hoocks();
```